# Put text under DIV images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put the text under my images with center alignment of the text in each image but it doesn't seem to work. Also is there anyway I can make this mobile compatible?

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r3u6B/

Here's the CSS of .p:

```
.imgcontainer p {
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
padding:1px;
border: 0px solid #c4c4c4;
margin:0px 37px 0px 0px;
width:175px;
height:175px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add `text-align:center` to your CSS.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/r3u6B/1/

So your adjusted code looks like this:

```
 .imgcontainer p {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  padding:1px;
  border: 0px solid #c4c4c4;
  margin:0px 37px 0px 0px;
  width:175px;
  height:175px;
  text-align:center;
  }
```

Comment: I'm such an idiot. Also is there anyway I can make this work on mobile devices?

Comment: 1.) yes, but you're better off using `%` not `px` for width & heights.
2.) Please encase `src=http://some..` with `src="http://some"` with quotations!

Comment: Will do and thank you. I have a question to ask you though... Is the a way I can use something like hide code if mobile device is present?

Comment: @user2680614 - as far as mobile... the code technically works on mobile, but your HTML is not formatted well to display on mobile.   For example, as MackieeE pointed out, forcing the display to 900px wide means it won't fit on most mobile devices.  You should consider using % instead.  You should also consider grouping your images and captions together...  this way when there is overflow to the next line, the images and their captions can move together.

Comment: @Charlie74 Should I set my % to 100? I want it to be include the full width of the page. Also I tried grouping my images together but it sent everything to the next line.